# How to change URL after build React project

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I got some build files after used the command of "npm run build" and then put the build files to our server. Now, I want to change some config files in the build files to change the fetch request. How should I do? Please help me.

(The url is changed by back-end developers, front-end developers just should read a file in the build files.)

Comment: You should share some more information. What are these build files? How do you want to change configs inside builded files? If the backend changes URLs, the client should get a way to ask the server for information. Therefore the backend needs a static URL.

Comment: I want to change the internal fetch request URL through the shell script command instead of getting the new URL through the network request.

Comment: To change something inside your builded files, you have to parse them, to find the part in the code where to change the URL. But I don't think this is how software in general should work.

Comment: OK! Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To mark this question as resolved:

For changing something inside the builded files, you have to parse them and find the part in the code where your URL is. Then you have to change it.

But I don't think this pattern is how software should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this. You have to edit the code and build it again. Then upload it afterwards. This is how react works.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, this is TERRIBLE practice! (but it worked in my case when I needed to change a link's href)

-Go to the static/js files folder and open your main.js
-Search for the url you need to change
-Change it